# Create Facebook type User in AD B2C With AD GraphAPI

Tags: facebook, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I have been trying to create a facebook type of user by graph api to avoid the signup process for a user who authenticates to the application using facebook login.(want the user to login with his existing fb account)
I have been able to create a AD user using Graph API but not the facebook type of user. I just found a article about b2c tenant user migration in this ([social user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-social-migration#migrate-social-account-only)) link which says about creating a facebook user account in b2c tenant using following json to be sent to Graph API as follows.

```
{
"objectId": null,
"accountEnabled": true,
"mailNickname": "c8c3d3b8-60cf-4c76-9aa7-eb3235b190c8",
"signInNames": [],
"creationType": null,
"displayName": "Sara Bell",
"givenName": "Sara",
"surname": "Bell",
"passwordProfile": {
    "password": "Test1234",
    "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
},
"passwordPolicies": null,
"userIdentities": [{
        "issuer": "Facebook.com",
        "issuerUserId": "MTIzNDU2Nzg5MA=="
    }
],
"otherMails": ["sara@live.com"],
"userPrincipalName": "c8c3d3b8-60cf-4c76-9aa7-eb3235b190c8@tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com"
```

}

when this happened there is a new user creatd in b2c tenant with the source as Facebook. But i have no idea how this user should login with facebook to authenticate.only an otheremails field has been provided in json. Please guide me on how to achieve this???

Comment: How to create a fb user with Ad Graph API where he can login to the application using his existing fb account

Comment: Any help please

Comment: There is no way to create Facebook accounts using the API.

Comment: @WizKid not to create facebook accounts but to create a user with a existing fb account so that he will be able to login to my app with facebook without a signup even in very first login.

Comment: In simple words I want my user to authenticate into my app using facebook. But for the first time when a user authenticates through facebook idp it redirects userfora signup. Becoz that user is still not created inside b2c tenant. That is why I want to create a social account type userwho can login with his existing fb account without redirecting to a signup

Comment: And im using ad graph api not ms graph api

Comment: Any help please

Comment: No clarification found so far..

Comment: We don't recommend you create Social identity providers via AAD Graph API. It doesn't make sense since the user should be created by the user sign up and get claims from the social IDP side, NOT creating by the admin.